# edge disjoin Cut Set

Tags: graph-theory, branch-cuts

prove that a graph G=(V,E) where | v | =n there are at most  n-1 edge disjoint cut sets.

I was thinking that for tree it is true since each edge is cut set. but i have no idea how to prove above statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $e \in E$ be arbitrary edge, consider two cases:

- $\{e\}$ is a cut-set, we can not remove that edge, because we could possibly decrease the number of disjoint cut-sets.
- $\{e\}$ is not a cut-set and we can remove it, we won't decrease the number of disjoint cut-sets (you need to argue why).

What is left after we have removed all the edges we could?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks for hint. We can use following argument to prove above statement if we use the  fact that each spanning tree of a graph contain at-least one edge of all possible cut sets of the graph. Since cut sets are edge disjoint that's why we can have at most n-1 edge disjoint cut sets. [each edge of spanning tree will represent one cut set].